# Name of dominated convergence for sums

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, summation

Having a sequence $(a_n(j))_{n}$ where every element of the sequence also depends on $j\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n(j)| < \infty$, then the following (assuming the limits exist) holds due to Lebesgue's dominated convergence.

$$\lim_{j\to\infty }\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n(j) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \lim_{j\to\infty} a_n(j).$$

Is there a name for this theorem which -  I would guess - was known before Lebesgue's dominated convergence? I have heard Weierstrass did something like this.

Comment: Why do you say it must be known before Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem? It need not, one can prove the dominated convergence theorem in its generality without using this special case.

Comment: I did not mean that it has to be known. It was just an idea. Sorry for the bad formulation.